# Header redirection on the same page

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I have small problem with part of my script:

```
<?php 

session_start();

include_once('../includes/connection.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
?>


    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1>Markup 1</h1>
    </body>
    </html>

<?php
} else {

    if(isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) {

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];         

        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email = ?");
        $query->bind_param('s',$email);
        $query->execute();

     $query->bind_result($user_id,$user_name,$user_email,$user_password);

        $query->fetch();

        $user = array("user_id"=>$user_id, "user_name"=>$user_name, "user_email"=>$user_email, "user_password"=>$user_password);


        if($user['user_id'] != 0) {

            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
            header("Location: index.php");
            die();

        } else {


            $error = "Incorrect details!";
        }
    }
}
 ?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Markup 2</h1>

<div class="container">
    <h3>Please login</h3>
    <?php if(isset($error)) { ?>
        <h4><?php echo $error; ?></h4>
    <?php } ?>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                <input type="submit" value="Login">

    </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem is that script after refreshing (calling header() method) doesn't execute die() statement, and after successfully set session variable and rendering part with "Markup 1" it will also render "Markup 2" part but it shouldn't.

I found this example here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNTvU--o2q8.

Comment: `Markup 1` and `Markup 2` will always be printed together. Take a closer look at the `if` statement. If you only want one of them then you need to terminate the script in the first `if` statement (otherwise it will just continue).

Comment: Have you even tried yet to just echo something in `if($user['user_id'] != 0) { }` to see if its really getting in there?

Comment: I'd say split this into some distinct pages instead of serving different html pages hardcoded in the same page via an if-else. That's just bad design in the sense of being ugly.

Comment: @developerwjk Ok, I know it is not great design as I said this is for learning purposes only. And when I try to echo something in that if statement you mentioned, it will be printed only if header method is commented out i don't know why... On yt video with that example everthing works well, but with my code something strange happens.

Comment: If its only printed when the header method is commented out, then it was actually redirecting the whole time after all! If you print something, then redirect, what you printed goes away because you left the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try including the second markup section within the else block this is a fairly hackish fix, but it should accomplish what you are aiming for. I would recommend restructuring this section and pulling some of the markup out to separate included files.

```
    <?php 

session_start();

include_once('../includes/connection.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
?>


    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1>Markup 1</h1>
    </body>
    </html>

<?php
} else {

    if(isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) {

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];         

        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email = ?");
        $query->bind_param('s',$email);
        $query->execute();

     $query->bind_result($user_id,$user_name,$user_email,$user_password);

        $query->fetch();

        $user = array("user_id"=>$user_id, "user_name"=>$user_name, "user_email"=>$user_email, "user_password"=>$user_password);


        if($user['user_id'] != 0) {

            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
            header("Location: index.php");
            die();

        } else {


            $error = "Incorrect details!";
        }
    } ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1>Markup 2</h1>

        <div class="container">
            <h3>Please login</h3>

            <?php if(isset($error)) { ?>

                <h4>

                    <?php echo $error; ?>

                </h4>

            <?php } ?>

            <form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </form>

        </div>
    </body>
    </html>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Its nice that you updated it to put that code in the else block, but it would be better to also indent it to where you can tell its in the else block.

Answer (score -1):

You can't call `header()` after you write content to the browser.  You can sort of hack around this in PHP using output buffers (it's been a long time), but really you should move code that handles headers above all of your markup.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Look closer. There is no output before the header.

Comment: Damn, you're right.  Been a long time since I did PHP, missed the condition.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen   You say that, but there still might be, if for instance there is a blank line above the first `<?php`

Comment: @developerwjk There could also be fairies interfering with the interpreter. Based on the code that we know about, output does not appear to be the problem.